# Velocity Verlet Algorithm: Cannot seem to determine correct velocity for stable Orbit?

Tags: objective-c, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

Like many that post about this topic, I too am busy trying to write myself an accurate simulator for the movement of objects in a 2D gravitation field.

I decided early on that I would settle on **Velocity Verlet** Integration, as I want my objects to maintain stable orbits and conserve energy even if the timestep is rather large. So, what might the problem be?

Well, so far, everything *seems* to behave correctly, except for one component. When I try to calculate the correct velocity for a stable orbit at a certain distance, the resulting velocity sends them into odd elliptical orbits that quickly increase in magnitude each time.

So, to begin, here are the following methods that determine an objects next position, velocity, and acceleration in scene: (Objective C)

**Acceleration:**

```
-(CGVector)determineAccelerationFor:(SKObject *)object
{ // Ok, let's find Acceleration! 
    CGVector forceVector = (CGVector){0,0}; // Blank vector that we will add forces to
    for (SKObject *i in self.sceneObjects)
    {
        if (![i isEqual:object]) // Just make sure we're not counting ourselves here
        {
            CGPoint distance = [self getDistanceBetween:i.position And:object.position]; 
            float hypotenuse = sqrtf(powf(distance.x, 2)+ powf(distance.y, 2));
            float force = ((self.gravity * object.mass * i.mass)/powf(hypotenuse, 3));

            float xMagnitude = (force * distance.x);
            float yMagnitude = (force * distance.y);
            forceVector.dx += xMagnitude;
            forceVector.dy += yMagnitude;
        }
    }
    CGVector acceleration = (CGVector){forceVector.dx/object.mass, forceVector.dy/object.mass};

    return acceleration;
}
```

Cool, so basically, I just take an object, add all the other forces that each other object imposes on it together then divide the X & Y factor by the mass of the current object to get the acceleration!

Next up is Velocity. Here I use the following equation:

[image]

The method for it is pretty straightforward too:

```
-(CGVector)determineVelocityWithCurrentVelocity:(CGVector)v OldAcceleration:(CGVector)ao NewAcceleration:(CGVector)a
{
    float xVelocity = (v.dx + ((ao.dx + a.dx)/2) * self.timeStep);
    float yVelocity = (v.dy + ((ao.dy + a.dy)/2) * self.timeStep);
    CGVector velocity = (CGVector){xVelocity,yVelocity};
    return velocity;
}
```

And finally, position! The equation for this is:

[image]

And it is determined with the following method!

```
-(CGPoint)determinePositionWithCurrentPosition:(CGPoint)x CurrentVelocity:(CGVector)v OldAcceleration:(CGVector)ao
{
    float xPosition = (x.x + v.dx * self.timeStep + ((ao.dx * powf(self.timeStep, 2))/2));
    float yPosition = (x.y + v.dy * self.timeStep + ((ao.dy * powf(self.timeStep, 2))/2));
    CGPoint position = (CGPoint){xPosition,yPosition};
    return position;
}
```

This is all called from the below method!!

```
-(void)refreshPhysics:(SKObject *)object
{

    CGPoint position = [self determinePositionWithCurrentPosition:object.position CurrentVelocity:object.velocity OldAcceleration:object.acceleration]; // Determine new Position



    SKAction *moveTo = [SKAction moveTo:position duration:0.0];
    [object runAction:moveTo]; // Move to new position

    CGVector acceleration = [self determineAccelerationFor:object]; // Determine acceleration off new position

    CGVector velocity = [self determineVelocityWithCurrentVelocity:object.velocity OldAcceleration:object.acceleration NewAcceleration:acceleration];
    NSLog(@"%@ Old Velocity: %f, %f",object.name,object.velocity.dx,object.velocity.dy);
    NSLog(@"%@ New Velocity: %f, %f\n\n",object.name,velocity.dx,velocity.dy);


    [object setAcceleration:acceleration];
    [object setVelocity:velocity];
}
```

Okay, so those methods above dictate how objects are moved in scene. Now onto the initial issue, the ever present problem of achieving a stable orbit!

In order to determine what velocity an object should have to maintain an orbit, I use the following equation: 
[image]

And I implement that as follows:

```
-(void)setObject:(SKObject *)object ToOrbit:(SKObject *)parent
{
    float defaultSeparation = 200;
    // Move Object to Position at right of parent
    CGPoint defaultOrbitPosition = (CGPoint){parent.position.x + (parent.size.width/2)+ defaultSeparation,parent.position.y};
    [object setPosition:defaultOrbitPosition];

    // Determine Orbital Velocity
    float velocity = sqrtf((self.gravity * parent.mass)/(parent.size.width/2+defaultSeparation));

    CGVector vector = (CGVector){0,velocity};
    [object setVelocity:vector];
}
```

And for some reason, despite this, I get abysmal results. Here is some of the output:

**Information:**

Gravity(constant) = **1000** (For test purposes)

Mass(Parent) = **5000 units**

Mass(Satellite) = **1 units**

Separation = **224 pixels**

It determines that in order for the Satellite to Orbit the Parent, a velocity of:

**149.403580 pixels/timeStep**

is required. And that checks out on my calculator.

So this has left me a little confused as to what could be going wrong. I log all the output concerning new velocities and positions, and it **does** use the velocity I set it to, but that just doesn't seem to make a difference. If anyone could possible help spot what's going wrong here I would be immensely grateful.

If anyone believes I have left something out, tell me and I will edit this right away. Thanks!

Comment: Your period for the numbers given is about 9.4 time units. If you are only taking 1 step per time unit, this could be the source of your problem. For example, after one unit of time, a test particle (limit of satellite mass negligible compared to parent) should move from (x,y)=(224,0) to (176,139), but the first step of your algorithm will take it to (174,149). This is already a 2.4% error in distance. Does reducing the timestep make things better? Simplectic integrators keep errors bounded (stability), but in the end your method is only 2nd order, so accuracy can be an issue.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I can test for this, but if you are correct, how can I maintain a relatively quick simulation without losing accuracy by increasing the timestep?

Comment: Use a better language? ;P Honestly, I have no idea about objective C, but I can tell you that doing a two-body (or even a hundred-body) simulation shouldn't even stress a modern processor running at any reasonable definition of "real time." If the code is slow, it's probably the result of all sorts of high-level nonsense getting in the way of computing what actually matters.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I can implement it in C. (I have one in C) But there are difficulties tying it to objects in the scene.

Comment: Well, see if smaller steps makes it work. Little point in optimizing code that doesn't work yet :)

Comment: @ChrisWhite Wait, what do you mean by timeStep? I do not list the timeStep in this question, it is only referred to as a property of the object. How are you deducing the period for my numbers?

Comment: You're right, I don't know exactly what step size you are using, which is why I'm not certain this is the problem. The period is just the circumference of the circle divided by the velocity.

Comment: @ChrisWhite My current timestep is small, something like 0.01 Do you advise simple decreasing that? It doesn't seem to affect the results. I believe they aren't supposed to be affected by timestep?